# How to center image in <li> elements?

Tags: html, css

I have a `ul` whose cells consist of an image and a text:

```
<ul class="special_ul">
  <li>
    <img src="img/solution_icon_optimize-efficnt.png">
    <a href = "">OTT</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="img/solution_icon_personal.png">
    <a href = "">Cloud Computing</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="img/solution_icon_diti-cx.png">
    <a href = "">Managed Services</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="img/solution_icon_biz-analitics.png">
    <a href = "">Social Media</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**css:**

```
.special_ul li{
    padding-right: 10px;
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}

.special_ul li img , .special_ul li a{
    display:block;
}
```

The problem is that the text is centered but the images are not:

[image: ul]

*(i highlighted the list with the mouse so you can see the images are not in the center)*

How do I make the images centered (horizontally) as well?

Comment: Frankly, you should be using a background image. It's better code (since the images are clearly styling) and it's makes centering them much easier.

Comment: change `display:block;` to `display:inline-block;` of `.special_ul li img , .special_ul li a{display:inline-block;}`

Comment: .special_ul li img --> display:inline-block;

Comment: It's also important to make sure that the images have the proper amount of white space or transparency on either side of the image. If the amount does not match between the sides the image as a whole will be centered, but the content of that image will not.

Comment: @Paulie_D , `background-image` won't set 1 image for them all? I need a different image for each `li`.
@0_o , That puts them in 1 line instead of one at the top of the other.

Comment: No, you would have to set a background image individually.

Comment: @Patrick548 - This actually turns to be the problem! There was transparent space on the sides. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just remove `img {display: block;}`, by default it is inline level, they will get centered with `text-align: center;` set on the container, which you already did.

Or, add `margin: 0 auto;` if you need to keep `display: block;` on the `img`:

```
.special_ul li img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```